# How does python differentiate an instance property from a decorated property with the same name?

Tags: python, class, recursion, python-decorators

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.price = value

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, value):
        self.price = value


p = Product(90)
```

Running the above code throws this error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` saying `self.price = value` was repeated multiple times. However when i prefix the `self.price` under the decorators `property` and `price.setter` with double underscores i.e `__self.price`, the error goes away.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.price = value

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.__price

    @price.setter
    def price(self, value):
        self.__price = value


p = Product(90)
```

What exactly do the doubleunderscores change?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because of the same naming convention of function and variable name. You first initialized your variable name as `price` and again you also declared your function name also `price`. Having the same naming convention price recalled infinitely and recursion crossed his limit thus you're getting this error. Try this out

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.price = value

    @property
    def prices(self):
        return self.price

    @prices.setter
    def prices(self, value):
        self.price = value


p = Product(90)
print(p.price)
```